# C# code to copy all the tables from one mdb file to another mdb file

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

how to copy all the tables from one mdb file to an other blank mdb file using C# code can anybody please help with the code?

Hi

Thanks for the file copy suggestion but after executing that query am getting this error"

```
 Error 1 Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    
 C:\Documents and Settings\E457808\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005
 \Projects\19032009\trymdbpulling\WindowsApplication1\Form1.cs  
 21 28  WindowsApplication1
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to just copy the file, e.g.

```
System.IO.File.Copy("source.mdb", "dest.mdb");
```

If you want only the structure without the data, you could make a template database with just the tables and copy from that.

Comment: I need to copy the tables along with the data in it.

Comment: Then you can use the code above, it will be far easier and faster than reading every table and making sql queries

Answer (score 0):

See this example of bulk copying: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CopyDBSchemaUsingSMO.aspx